# Create a unique reference for a transaction in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working a payment gateway project on ASP.NET Core Web API 6.0.

For a successful transaction request, we need to send a key named as "vendorTxCode" which should have a unique value for each transaction.

How to create a unique value in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`?

Comment: If you want to create a unique identifier a guid is usually great. The chance of collision is so small that you can rely on it being unique and it's a standard format that's compatible in many different languages and systems.

Comment: You can also try Twitter's Snowflake.